# How to change import module name "env" in wasm?

Tags: clang, emscripten, webassembly

1. In a wasm source code, when an undefined function is used, the compile will add this function into module named "env".
2. I want to change the name "env" to another like "myenv"

```c
#include <stdio.h>
extern int butt();
int main()
{
    butt();
    printf("123\n");
}
```

the wast file looks like this

```
(import "env" "butt" (func $butt (result i32)))
```

How to change my c-code so that the "butt" is under "myenv".
That's what I expect for.

```
(import "myenv" "butt" (func $butt (result i32)))
```

I'm using clang compiler to generate wasm file.

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no way to change the default, but for a given symbol you can use the `import_name` attribute:

https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#import-module